# How to get all the images in a PDPage?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am a little bit stuck with my code. I have to extract all the images from a PDF page for comparison. I retrieve the current page, and then I get the resources, then I don't know how to retrieve all the images on that page.

```
PDPage page = (PDPage)this.document.getDocumentCatalog().getPages().get(i);
PDResources resources = page.getResources();
```

I have seen that PDFBox has changed slightly in the last versions, and now I am confused.

Comment: Do you really want all images in the resources of the page? Or do you want all images actually used on the page?

Comment: i want all the images used on that specific PDF page.

Comment: *"all the images used on that specific PDF page"* - The PDFBox example `PrintImageLocations` should show how to retrieve them.